# Why does sscanf %lx read "0" for any first uint32_t on a 64-bit environment?

Tags: c, hex, 32-bit, scanf

I have the following C code:

```
uint32_t a = 1, b = 2;
sscanf("0xbadf00d 0xdeadbeef", "%lx %lx", &a, &b);
printf("%lx %lx", a, b);
```

On a 64-bit Linux machine using gcc, if I compile with the flag `-m32` I get the correct output: `badf00d deadbeef`, but by default I get the strange output `0 deadbeef`.

What is going on in the second case? Am I using the wrong conversion specifier character, or, is there a way to fix the problem without this compiler flag?

Comment: Are you used to programming on Windows?  On Windows, `long` is 32 bits.  Almost everywhere else, `long` is the same width as a pointer—so, 32 bits on 32-bit systems, and 64 bits on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Yes; that was the source of my confusion

Comment: I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04 on a amd64 cpu.  With no `-m32` parameter, the compiler raises several warnings.  After correcting all those warnings, the code compiles with no problems and outputs the correct values.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `l` length modifier, which is for `unsigned long`, but `uint32_t` is *not* unsigned long on 64-bit systems, with the sole exception of Windows.  There isn't a standard length modifier for `uint32_t` defined, but there are macros in a header which contain the length modifier (which is usually an empty string).

The portable solution is to use the macros defined in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t a = 1, b = 2;
    sscanf("0xbadf00d 0xdeadbeef", "%" SCNx32 " %" SCNx32, &a, &b);
    printf("%" PRIx32 " %" PRIx32, a, b);
}
```

On almost any system you actually use, this is the same as the following, after macro expansion:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    uint32_t a = 1, b = 2;
    sscanf("0xbadf00d 0xdeadbeef", "%x %x", &a, &b);
    printf("%x %x", a, b);
}
```